# How to Insert HTML code to database using json and django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add HTML template code directly into database in django-rest-framework.
And want to use json as retrieve and add the html code. How can I do this?

```
class AddHTML(models.Model):
template_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
HTML_code       = models.TextField(default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.template_name
```

serializer.py

```
class AddHTMLSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = AddHTML
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class HTMLData(APIView):
def get(self, request, format=None):
    html = AddHTML.objects.all()
    serializer = AddHTMLSerializer(html, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = AddHTMLSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class HTMLDataDetail(APIView):
def get_object(self, id):
    try:
        return AddHTML.objects.get(id=id)
    except AddHTML.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def get(self, request, id, format=None):
    html = self.get_object(id)
    serializer = AddHTMLSerializer(html)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def put(self, request, id, format=None):
    html = self.get_object(id)
    serializer = AddHTMLSerializer(html, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, id, format=None):
    html = self.get_object(id)
    html.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here in views what should I do that without loosing any tags of HTML data I could easily save and retrieve from database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing and retrieving the HTML shouldn't be an issue, since it's just being stored as text, just make sure all your characters are escaped properly. (i.e., `\\` in your HTML string instead of `\`)

Now, rendering the HTML via the template is a little bit more tricky, but not too bad. You'll have to create a Template object with your HTML:

```
db_value = 'Put the HTML from database here'
db_template = Template(db_value)
db_context = Context({'variables': 'Anything you want passed to the template goes here'})
```

From there, you can render the template using `db_template.render(db_context)`.

However, you can also just pass the HTML string to a pre-defined template and handle the rendering on that end, either with the Django template system and/or JavaScript.